# Google Sign In - Signed APK vs Running through Android studio

Tags: android, google-signin

First off, I have tried almost everything that has been suggested on this forum regarding why sign in doesn't work. Before I get into what I tried, here is the problem.

I try signing in with a Google account, and after clicking on the account I want it does nothing.

This is a group project and it seems to work for the other members. I have tried copying debug.keystore to my computer countless times and still that doesn't help. I have tried using a signed apk and again no luck.

What's wierd is that when a colleague extracts the app from his phone and sends me the apk it works. But if I make changes on my end and update the app it Bo longer works. At this point if I try to REINSTALL his apk, it now doesn't work. I honestly have no idea why, or what else I can do it fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Logcat display when trying to login

```
09-27 16:05:11.109 30143-30143/com.m D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
09-27 16:05:11.124 30143-30143/com.m D/AbstractTracker: Event success
09-27 16:05:11.124 30143-30143/com.m D/AbstractTracker: Event success
09-27 16:05:11.150 30143-30143/com.m D/AbstractTracker: Event success
09-27 16:05:13.483 30143-30143/com.m D/SignInActivity: handleSignInResult:false
09-27 16:05:13.483 30143-30319/com.m V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 669432745
09-27 16:05:13.484 30143-30143/com.m D/AppTracker: App Event: start
09-27 16:05:13.509 30143-30143/com.m D/AbstractTracker: Event success
09-27 16:05:14.736 30143-30319/com.m V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
```

Also note: The status code of handleResult is 4, according to the [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#SIGN_IN_REQUIRED) is SIGN_IN_REQUIRED

**UPDATE**

So I can successfully generate a signed apk and have google sign in working. One thing i learnt from this is that the default password for the keystore is android.

However, when I try to 'run' using the green run button on my selected device, I get this warning.

> Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE.

So i uninstall the app and android studio installs the apk. Now google sign in does not work.

**How can I get google sign in to work through the run button?** I dont want to have to consistently generate a signed apk everytime i want to test a change. Or if I want to run it on the android emulator.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: A full stack trace will be beneficial in this case. Did you try debugging the app ? What does the logcat show ?

Comment: All that is returned is handleSignInResult:false

Comment: Don't forget that you can switch your build variant in Android Studio. With specifying 'release' as you build variant you can run signed app on emulator directly from AS. Also sometimes I get INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE even after uninstalling app because its is installed for different user on device, just make sure to uninstall for all users